# What is the most efficient way to add a jQuery UI slider to future elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Currently, I am reloading a section of my site with AJAX which has sliders from jQuery UI. Those sliders are not reloaded because in my javascript, they are only loaded on DOM.

### `core.js`

```
$(function() {
    $('.slider').slider();

    $('#load').click(function() {
       $.getScript('load.js');

    });
});
```

### `load.js`

```
$('#foobar').html('<div class="slider"></div><div class="slider"></div>');
```

### `index.html`

```
<a href="#" id="load">Click</a>
<div id="foobar">
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

I suppose this would be the same as adding sliders to future elements. I've looked at `.delegate()` and `.live()` and I can't get those to work for my situation. Any suggestions?

I am looking for a way to solve this as unobtrusively as possible.

Comment: need to see the ajax call to help

Answer (score 0):

In the ajax callback function you can tell jquery ui to reinstate all callbacks just like you created them `$('.sliders').slider();`
Or if you are adding them dynamically you can do something like this:

```
var $slider = $("<div class='slider'></div>");
$slider.slider();
$slider.appendTo("#sliders");
```

[JS Fiddle link for my example](http://jsfiddle.net/2jqgm/)

**Edit:**
Try this code:

```
$.getScript('load.js', function(){
  $('.sliders').slider();
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it less obstrusively?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this a little differently. let me know why or why not you prefer the following method.

**`core.js`**

```
$(function() {
    $('.slider').slider();

    $('#load').click(function() {
       $.ajax
       (
           url: 'load.html',//url for ajax call
           //run function on success. the contents is passes as @param data or whatever you choose
           success: function(data)
           {
                $('#foobar').html(data);//add to dom
                //bind here 
                $('.slider').slider()//if this line doesnt work use delegate 
           }
    });
});
```

**`load.html`**

```
<div class="slider"></div><div class="slider"></div>
```